# Polymer data binding, "with" statement?

Tags: polymer, with-statement

Given this example from the polymer documentation:

```
<template repeat="{{item in items}}">
  <tr><td> {{item.name}} </td><td> {{item.count}} </td></tr>
</template>
```

Let's say "item" had dozens of properties and I didn't want to type "item.property" every time.  Is there any functionality similar to a typical With statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't define an scope:

```
<template repeat="{{items}}">
  <tr><td> {{name}} </td><td> {{count}} </td></tr>
</template>
```